# Get date from date field and store into content entity

Tags: 8, datetime

I'm wondering how I can grab the date from a datepicker in a form (format is d/m/Y) and store it into my content entity. The form is produced from said content entity, so I don't see why there should be any issues between formats - but it doesn't copy directly. I know the date fields are stored as varchar(20) in the database, so it must be a string at some stage!

I'm grabbing the value from my form as below:

```
$dob = $form_state->get('field_dob');
$given = new DrupalDateTime($dob, \Drupal::currentUser()->getTimezone());
$given->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$dob = $given->format(DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);
```

This gives me a string formatted as per the storage format, yet still won't copy across to the corresponding content entity.

Also, this is with Drupal 8.1.x. :)

Any insight would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The crucial part of the code seems to be missing. how do you assign $dob to your entity?

Comment: @Berdir $private_profile->set('field_dob', $dob);

Comment: If that's a normal content entity form, isn't field_dob an array with nested elements? Why don't you get those values from the already built content entity and just assign $entity->field_dob->value to the other entity?